# Recovering my old bitcoin wallet

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, encryption

As far as I can tell, my old bitcoin wallet got corrupted. It was created in Bitcoin Core in the 2014/2015s, and I'm trying to recover it. Bitcoin Core doesn't accept it anymore (and doesn't give an error message), so I'm trying another way.

I managed to read the contents using walletools (https://github.com/akx/walletool), and here is what I have :

- a long list of "tx" items, containing mostly binary data
- quite a few (probably 50 ish) "ckey" items, with the public key and encrypted private keys
- a single "mkey" item, with the 'nID', 'encrypted_key', 'salt', 'derivationMethod', 'nDerivationIterations' and 'otherParams' fields containing data
- two "name" items containing 'hash' and 'name' fields
- a number of "pool" items with 'n', 'nVersion', 'nTime', and the 'public_key'
- lots of empty "keymeta" items
- a "version" item : 150001
- a "bestblock" item, with a "key" field
- a "minversion" item : 130000
- a "orderposnext" item (empty)
- a "bestblock_nomerkle" item (empty)

From there, I imagine the important data is the mkey. What is its encryption algorithm and what Python lib could I use to decrypt it (assuming I remember the password ! ) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the least "intense" option here would be to look up each of the wallet addresses from your `ckey` items on a node (i.e. blockchain.info blockchair.com btc.com etc) to see which ones have any value in them.

Once you have a list of the wallet addresses that are "worth recovering," you will need to take those `ckey` items' encrypted private keys (possibly along with data from the `mkey` item) to attempt to manually decrypt/recover your private keys to those wallets.

If you're experienced with programming, you could read through the code from the version of bitcoin core you used in 2014/2015 to figure out how it was encoded. Otherwise, you may need to find an experienced programmer you can trust, to help here.

As a post-note:
Have you tried re-compiling a copy of that older version of bitcoin core on a sandbox system? It's just a try, but maybe the file just got caught by a reverse-compatibility issue!

Comment: Well sadly, I have no idea what version I used exactly, so I may be out of luck going this way. Reading the code is no problem for me though, but if I have to iterate through all the commits to see what changed and at what point, this may not be so much of a trivial task... I will try to pick one and see if it loads it :)